# NSString and NSMutableString methods and casting via mutableCopy

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Coming from a C++ background, I'm amazed that I have to write the following code to avoid warnings:

```
NSMutableString *foobar = [@"foobar" mutableCopy]; // line 1
foobar = [[foobar capitalizedString] mutableCopy]; // line 2
```

Line 1 seems perfectly normal to me: you can't directly cast a const string to string.

Line 2 is what puzzles me: capitalizedString is a method that belongs to NSString and returns a NSString. So in order to affect it to a NSMutableString you must "recast" it via mutableCopy.

But why isn't capitalizedString overloaded in NSMutableString like "-(NSMutableString*) capitalizedString" ?

If that were the case, we could simply write the following with no warnings:

```
foobar = [foobar capitalizedString]; // line 2
```

PS: I know I could write both lines in a single one, but this is for the example.

Comment: It's because you are daft to have an NSMutableString in the first place. NSString* foobar = [@"foobar" capitalizedString] works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

> So in order to affect it to a NSMutableString you must "recast" it via mutableCopy

`mutableCopy` is not a "recast" as in C++. It creates a mutable copy. There is recasting in ObjC, and this isn't it. The distinction is important because "recast" suggests that you're taking a single object and just treating it a different way. `mutableCopy` creates a new object, which has memory management implications. (Those are now handled mostly by ARC, but they are still important for understanding what's going on.)

> But why isn't capitalizedString overloaded in NSMutableString like "-(NSMutableString*) capitalizedString" ?

Objective-C does not have overloading. So this is impossible, even if it were desirable. Whether it is actually desirable is an interesting question. In some use cases it could be more convenient. In other use cases it would be less convenient (immutable strings have optimizations available that mutable strings lose, so if I wanted those optimizations, I would have to copy the string yet again to make it immutable). But it's moot; overloads are not possible. So to have what you're asking for, you'd have to create `-mutableCapitalizedString`, just like we have `copy` and `mutableCopy`. (That'd be silly, because `capitalizedString` is pretty rare.)

As @Zaph points out, `NSMutableString` is somewhat uncommon in ObjC. That said, your questions also apply to `-sortedArrayUsingSelector:`, so the basic question is valid.

It's worth noting that Swift does have overloads, and what you're describing could be done in Swift (though it would break type inference, so in most cases it would probably be annoying). But overloads were something that Swift saw as valuable to add. ObjC just doesn't have them.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/capitalizedString) the internal implementation of `capitalizedString` method is like that below which contains `readonly` and `copy` attributes.

```
@property(readonly, copy) NSString *capitalizedString
```

So if invoke the `capitalizedString` method it will return the `NSString`object . So in order to affect it to a `NSMutableString` object it is required to use the `mutableCopy`

Answer (score 1):

`[foobar capitalizedString]` returns a `NSString` but `foobar` was declared `NSMutableString` so a mutable version needs to be created in order to assign.

```
NSString *foobar = @"foobar";
foobar = [foobar capitalizedString];
// Create a new instance `NSString` instance and assigns it to the same `NSString` pointer `foobar`.
```

Why use `NSMutableString`? In Objective-C using mutable objects are not commonly used/needed.

Comment: I view NSString as "const char* / const std::string" and NSMutableString as "char */ std::string".

After your comment, I tested around, and it doesn't seem to be that way: an NSString can be modified.

Comment: An `NSString` can not be modified, a new (modified instance) can be assigned to the same pointer. This is the typical pattern. The pointer is not `const`, the `NSString` instance is immutable. It is possible to create const pointers in Objective-C.

Comment: @BlakBat: Your view is incorrect. There are mutable objects, and immutable objects. It's rare that you use mutable objects. Read a good introduction into Objective-C. Hint: It's not the same as C++.

Comment: @gnasher729, mutable objects are extremely common in ObjC. `NSMutableString` isn't that common, but `NSMutableArray` is all over the place. As @Zaph points out, though, C++'s `const` is not a good way to think about `NSString`. `NSString` is just a class and `NSMutableString` is just a subclass of it. They don't have compiler-enforced mutability semantics. `NSString` just happens to have no mutating methods.

Comment: It's worth noting that `NSMutableString` ISA `NSString`. That means that it is possible for an `NSString` to mutate behind your back. This is something ObjC developers actually defend against (we make defensive calls to `copy` on `NSString` objects we're passed).